# Play Framework and Maven generating sources never ends

Tags: scala, maven, playframework, exec-maven-plugin

I am working on a web application with PLAY Framework 2.8.13, Scala and Maven for the back and with React for the front. I am using a script to build the front with maven as follows :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>npm-install</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>${project.basedir}/install-front.sh</executable>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run my backend server with `mvn play2:run` the source generation never ends and nothing happens, the console freeze on :

`[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:4.5.4:script ...`

Strangely, when I change the phase `generate-source` to `clean`, the error no longer occurs and everything is going well

However I can't use this solution because `mvn release` bypass `clean` phase and the compilation fails

Comment: You might have a hidden missing dependency for some artifact, Can you try running: `mvn clean generate-sources`  - it might show the artifact that cannot resolve it. Usually, `generate-sources` works as long as you have every dependency inside your repo, not near it, but inside.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however it didn't work .. I don't know why but there is a conflict between these two plugins and the execution never happen. For the moment I found a solution by skipping exec-maven-plugin with `-Dexec.skip` but I would like to understand why this is happening